# Image Upload in Jquery using Spring?

Tags: java, jquery, spring, image-uploading

Actually I'm doing Sample Application,

We are Observe many of social networks, in that Profile images are their, When ever mouse over it is asking Upload new Image.

So i want to Develop Same Application .

When ever we write `<input type="file"/>` then it is asking file and now add value(image) into .. So how to add this value.

Their is only one click browse image and upload image...

And now how to handle this one into Spring side..

Please Suggest me..

Comment: Yhe I was wondering the samething.

Answer (score 0):

I thing you need to use ajax to do this. Click [here](http://articles.tutorboy.com/2010/03/31/orkut-style-profile-picture-upload-using-jquery-and-ajaxupload/) to see a demo in PHP. They show how to done that in PHP. Instead of PHP you can use Spring with JSON to complete that.